# Replace column after performing actions using awk

Tags: shell, awk, gsub

Below here I'm trying to remove comma only from msg column.

Input file (**"abc.txt"** has many entries as below):

```
alert tcp any any -> any [10,112,34] (msg:"Its an Test, Rule"; reference:url,view/Main; sid:1234; rev:1;)
```

Expected Output:

```
alert tcp any any -> any [10,112,34] (msg:"Its an Test Rule"; reference:url,view/Main; sid:1234; rev:1;)
```

This is what i have tried using awk:

```
awk -F ';' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(match($i,"msg:")>0){split($i, array, "\"");tmessage=array[2];gsub("[',']","",tmessage);message=tmessage; }}print message'} abc.txt
```

Comment: Try with (GNU) `sed`: `sed '/(msg:"/ {:a s/\((msg:"[^",]*\),/\1/; t a}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this logic also works in non-GNU sed if you separate some of the pieces: `sed -e '/(msg:"/ {:a' -e 's/\((msg:"[^",]*\),/\1/;t a' -e '}'`

Comment: @ghoti Thanks for letting know, I have never used a non-GNU sed so far.

Comment: @mahi, you NEVER selected an answer as correct answer, so please take sometime to check all answers of users here and then select anyone of them as correct answer which helped you to close the thread properly, cheers.

Comment: or simply with sed: sed ':A;s/\(msg:"[^,"]*\),/\1/;tA'

Answer (score 0):

The problem with having awk rewrite your fields is that output for modified lines will be field-separated by OFS, which is static.

The way around this is to avoid dealing with fields, and just handle the string replacement on `$0`. You could piece together the parts of the line manually, like this:

```
awk '{x=index($0,"msg:"); y=index(substr($0,x),";"); s=substr($0,x,y); gsub(/,/,"",s); print substr($0,1,x-1) s substr($0,x+y)}' input.txt
```

Or spelled out for easier reading:

```
{
  x=index($0,"msg:")                     # find the offset of the interesting bit
  y=index(substr($0,x),";")              # find the length of that bit
  s=substr($0,x,y)                       # clip the bit
  gsub(/,/,"",s)                         # replace commas,
  print substr($0,1,x-1) s substr($0,x+y)  # print the result.
}
```